# UIView over UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I need to place a `UIView` over `UITableViewController`, for now i placed it this way

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:searchView];
```

But problem is that - when i push this `UITableViewController` by another - my `UIView` is not pushed away with `UITableViewController`, but still hang up there, of course i just can remove it with animation, but it looks crapy enough

Is there a way to make that my UIView will be cover another VC together with `UITableViewController`?

Thanks!

Comment: Before push to other view controller, just do that `[searchView removeFromSuperview];`. Then push....

Comment: I would recommend to use a standard UIViewController that holds a UITableView and a UIView so you hide/show either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewControllers` in fact also have a `view` property which you can add subviews to. So my advice would be to just send `[self.view addSubview:searchView];` inside the table view controller, so that it will be moved alongside the table view, when pushing another controller.

Comment: Thank you!)) It works!!!!) But i'm already make UITableViewController embed into UIViewController and it was much more difficult then your solution((

Comment: Ups! - there is a little mistake, [self.view addSubview:searchView] - it works, but it placed UIView on the scroll view (not over), and when i'm scrolling my table - UIView is scrolling together with it. Obviously there is only one right solution - put UITableViewController into ContainerView which placed inside of UIVewController

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `[self.view addSubview:searchView]` as in that case `self.view` is UITableview only so this will add the searchview on tableview and your view will also scroll with the tableview.
You can use

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:searchView];
```